# Unable to write Unit Test for JPA repository ,receiving Could not fetch the SequenceInformation from the database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I want to write JUnit test for the repository file

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<EmployeeRepository, Long> {
}
```

Which is using the entity

```
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity @Table(name = "employee_definition")
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
@Builder @Getter @Setter @ToString
public class EmployeeDefinition  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "employee_definition_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "employee_definition_generator",
            sequenceName = "employee_definition_sequence",
            initialValue = 1
    )
    private Long id;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private Object employeeDetails;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false)
    private Date created_at;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String created_by;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private Date updated_at;

    @Column(name = "updated_by")
    private String updated_by;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "deleted_at")
    private Date deleted_at;

    @Column(name = "deleted_by")
    private String deleted_by;

}
```

I have application-test.properties as

```
server.port=8081
spring.jpa.database: HSQL
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

My test file for employee repository is

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;

@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class EmployeeRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

   @Test
   public void employeeDefinitionModel_created(){
    EmployeeDefinition employeeModel = EmployeeDefinition.builder().created_at(new Date()).created_by("test").employeeDefinition("").build();
    System.out.println("---------------------------"+employeeRepository.save(employeeModel));
   }

}
```

While running this test case i am getting error message like

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.1.RELEASE)

2020-03-13 17:42:33.292  INFO 62941 --- [           main] c.a.s.r.EmployeeRepositoryTest      : The following profiles are active: test
2020-03-13 17:42:33.698  INFO 62941 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-03-13 17:42:33.764  INFO 62941 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 57ms. Found 2 repository interfaces.
2020-03-13 17:42:33.805  INFO 62941 --- [           main] beddedDataSourceBeanFactoryPostProcessor : Replacing 'dataSource' DataSource bean with embedded version
2020-03-13 17:42:33.973  INFO 62941 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:hsqldb:mem:55e2cf4b-1e88-4911-962e-c44e0f598020', username='sa'
2020-03-13 17:42:34.386  INFO 62941 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-03-13 17:42:34.469  INFO 62941 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.8.Final}
2020-03-13 17:42:34.591  INFO 62941 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-03-13 17:42:34.693  INFO 62941 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
2020-03-13 17:42:34.835  WARN 62941 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [pg-uuid]
2020-03-13 17:42:34.839  INFO 62941 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-03-13 17:42:34.846 ERROR 62941 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [pg-uuid]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1803) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:125) ~[spring-boot-test-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [pg-uuid]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:133) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.ClassLoaderAccessImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderAccessImpl.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder.fillSimpleValue(SimpleValueBinder.java:538) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SetSimpleValueTypeSecondPass.doSecondPass(SetSimpleValueTypeSecondPass.java:25) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1684) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1642) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1245) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 81 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : pg-uuid
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:130) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    ... 96 common frames omitted
```

Kindly help me out in writing unit test for Employeerepository with EmployeeDefinition as entity , I need to verify save operation of JPA repository.
And I also have doubt from where is the column **start_value** is taken , because i had not used in entity , whether it is something that belongs to EntityManagerFactory.

Comment: Don´t know if it is of importance here but HSQL and H2 are two different databases. So spring.jpa.database: HSQL
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver seems to conflict.

Comment: Indeed you have a mess in  application-test.properties. Database is HSQL, driverClassName is from H2, dialect is for Postgres

Comment: Because you're adapting your config for PostgreSQL, I assume you're also targeting such a database... Does a sequence with name `employee_definition_sequence` exist in your local database?

Comment: @C.Weber   , Thank you for the response now i had updated the application-test.properties as above ,Now i am receiving error message like      Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class] , How i need to configure it

Comment: @0x1C1B, I had changed my config to HSQL , No **employee_definition_sequence** does not exist in hsql , whether the unit test file create new sequence name as mentioned above

Comment: @monesh Please provide a full error report... Not quite sure if this solves your problem but your referencing a custom sequence that must exist in database but you drop it with every test run

Comment: @0x1C1B, I had updated the question , i had attached full error report

Comment: Thank you everyone for participation, once i changed application-test.properties issues got fixed